# Indexing of pd.Series inside and outside of for-loop - comprehension question

Tags: python, pandas

I've stumbled across a problem that I don't quite understand. In a script I'm indexing both lists and pandas series both inside and outside of for-loops, and I've noticed that the indexing seems to work differently.

Minimal code example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num = 5
x1 = pd.Series([0]*num) # initiate series of zeros
x2 = [0]*num            # initiate list of zeros
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y2 = [5,6,7,8,9]

for i in range(num):
    x1[i] = np.divide(y1[i],y2[i])
    x2[i] = np.divide(y1[i],y2[i])
x1[i] = 5
x2[i] = 5

print('x1 = ',x1)
print('x2 = ',x2)
```

Now I get the following output:

```
x1 =  0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    5
dtype: int64
x2 =  [0.2, 0.3333333333333333, 0.42857142857142855, 0.5, 5]
```

So somehow inside the for-loop I don't seem to be able to index the pandas series variable and reassign a value simply by saying `x1[i]`, but outside the for-loop it is possible (as is evident from the output for x1 at index 4). At the same time, for the list object, it makes no difference whether I'm inside or outside the for-loop.

Can anyone explain why?

**Note:** I am aware that I can solve my problem by using `x1.iloc[i]`inside the for-loop. I'm just trying to understand why this difference exists, or what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the dtype of your pandas series is `int64` after initializing it like this (as you can see in your output).
So assigning floats to elements of this series will always cut all decimals.

Try e.g.

```
x1[2] = 3.4
```

and it will hold `3`.

Or within the loop

```
x1[i] = np.divide(y1[i],y2[i]) + 7
```

and there will be `7`s in there...

So to solve this, you would e.g. only have to add one single decimal sign to the right of the `0` at initialization:

```
x1 = pd.Series([0.]*num) # initiate series of Zeros
```

Then the data type will be `float64` and your test will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know why it does work with `.iloc` ? As far as I understood `.iloc` was simply a way of accessing a given index, but it turns out it allows the dtype to be changed whereas direct indexing does not.

Comment: No, sorry - tbh I don't know the implementation details or reasons of these two indexing methods.